# Paypal Success transation return values empty-- sometimes

Tags: string, paypal, confirmation

There is a problem with my paypal Integration in live site.

For 90% of transactions, I didn't get any problem. Some times only I am facing this below problem.

Problem: **After successful transaction, I am not getting Pay pal values like Transaction Id, Message etc. All values shows empty. It comes for 10% of transactions only. please tell me what may be the problem. Can't able to find out the reason**

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Is this for the API or IPN?

Comment: API only. One more thing i observed that, From last couple of transaction paypal even doesn't send back to my website after successful transaction. I checked in my paypal transaction history, all are success. But not updated in my website.  Is there anything i need to change in my merchant account?

Comment: Can you post some calls or elaborate on what's failing? Your question is still vague.

Comment: Thanks Machavity for your quick response. The problem is i am not able  redirect automatically  to my website after completion of transaction. But, Some time it will with empty array values. This is working fine for test account, but not live account

Comment: Can you post your `SetExpressCheckout` call?

Answer (score 0):

```
$paypal_email = '5345345345345f';

$cur_dir='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$return_url = $cur_dir.'/paymentsucess.php'; 

$cancel_url = $cur_dir.'/payment-not-sucess.php';

$notify_url = $cur_dir.'/payments.php';


extract($_POST);

$item_name = $exam_name;

$item_amount = $amount;
$userid=$userid;


if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
$querystring = "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

$querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";

$querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";



//loop for posted values and append to querystring

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));

     $querystring .= "$key=$value&";

}


$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";

$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";

$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);
 header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
exit();
}else{
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));

    $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)  (.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix

    $req .= "&$key=$value";

}

$data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];

$data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];

$data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];

$data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];

$data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];

$data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];

$data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];

$data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];

$data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];

$data['userid']             = $_POST['userid'];

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";



$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);



if (!$fp) {

    // HTTP ERROR

} else {

fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) {

        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {



            // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)

            $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);

            $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);

            // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!

            if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){



                $orderid = updatePayments($data);

                if($orderid){

                }else{


                }

            }else{


            }

        }else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

        }

    }

fclose ($fp);

}

}
```